# Ошибка: Forbidden - You don't have permission to access

Tags: apache, cgi, localhost

Не получается настроить виртуальные хосты.

Я когда-то успешно поднял на Windows 7 apache+php, так вот теперь потребовалось сделать парочку виртуальных хостов. Я добавил в конец конфига апача секцию вида

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2>
  ServerAdmin yourmail@domain.com
  ServerName jiifirst
  DocumentRoot "c:/apache2/web/jiifirst/htdocs"
  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "c:/apache2/web/jiifirst/cgi-bin/"
  ErrorLog c:/apache2/web/jiifirst/logs/error.log
  CustomLog c:/apache2/web/jiifirst/logs/access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Создал нужные папки. Однако при попытке захода по http://127.0.0.2/test.php возникает ошибка

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /test.php on this server.

При этом на локалхост хожу без проблем. Как поменять настройки, чтобы такой ошибки не возникало?

Answer (score 1):

1. Нужно настроить права доступа на файл test.php. То есть r (читать), w (писать/редактировать), x(выполнять). Как это сделать на локальном сервере я не знаю. Делал когда-то через консоль. Погуглите по правам доступа
2. Советую пройти по этой ссылке http://ab-w.net/PHP/server_set.php и уже по инструкции получить полностью настроенный локальный сервер, у меня заняло всего 30 минут и работает уже полгода без проблем.

Comment: Понимаете, это мой личный сервер на домашнем компьютере, поэтому я хочу сделать там все по-своему. В общем, я бы выставил права, но как в винде это делать не знаю - только в юниксе